# The chromedriver version cannot be discovered selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was using the following code in selenium Python:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=options)
```

Everything was running fine but Suddenly I see the following error after upgrading google chrome.

**The chromedriver version cannot be discovered**

[image]

I am using selenium 4.14.0 version.

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on Windows OS, try deleting the drivers (`chromedriver.exe`) which will be in your `~/.cache/selenium/chromedriver` folder and retry running the code. See if it downloads the correct driver as per your latest chrome browser version.

Path where the `SeleniumManager` downloads the drivers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

1. install the driver using `chromedriver-autoinstaller`
   install package `chromedriver-autoinstaller` `pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller`

   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
   import chromedriver_autoinstaller
   chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
   options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(), options=options)
2. add the `chromedriver.exe` service path directly

   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
   options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service("C:/Users/yourusername/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/win32/112.0.5615.49/chromedriver.exe"),options=options)